# Creating pandas DataFrame column from selected values from another column

Tags: python, pandas

Say, I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : list('abcdefghij'), 'b' : (5*[2] + 5*[3])})
```

And I want to create another column which contains those values from column `'a'` which are indexed in column `'b'` (5 times 'c' and 5 times 'd').  Then, it would seem natural for me to do something like this:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].iloc[df['b']]
```

But that produces an error:

```
cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

My question is

a) how can I do that?

b) where can I learn about the actual mechanics of Pandas indices, as opposed to the intuition?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, `df[df['a'].isin(df['b'])]` will return the values of 'a' that are present in 'b' but you seem to be overwriting 'b' with essentially the same values

Comment: @EdChum I guess, assigning to the same column and using values for `a` that are identical to the index was a bit misleading.  I've changed the question; does that make more sense?

Comment: I still don't understand what expected output you want, if you just want the values of the relevant columns (exclude the indexes) you can just use `.values`: `df['c'] = df['a'].iloc[df['b']].values`

Comment: So are you after `df['c'] = df.loc[df['b'],'a']`?

Comment: @ EdChum: Yes, but that still gives me the same error.
@ Anzel: That works, thanks a lot!  Explain why that works and the other thing doesn't in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
In [219]:
df['c'] = df.loc[df['b'],'a'].values
df

Out[219]:
   a  b  c
0  a  2  c
1  b  2  c
2  c  2  c
3  d  2  c
4  e  2  c
5  f  3  d
6  g  3  d
7  h  3  d
8  i  3  d
9  j  3  d
```

As to why you get the 'cannot reindex from duplicate axis' if you observe what it's returning:

```
In [220]:
df.loc[df['b'],'a']

Out[220]:
2    c
2    c
2    c
2    c
2    c
3    d
3    d
3    d
3    d
3    d
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Then it should be clear why it moans, the index values are repeating and pandas is trying to align the index against your original df, to get around this you can get the raw values as a np array by calling `.values` attribute:

```
In [221]:
df.loc[df['b'],'a'].values

Out[221]:
array(['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'], dtype=object)
```